# SQLAlchemy classes across files

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to figure out how to have SQLAlchemy classes spread across several files, and I can for my life not figure out how to do it. I am pretty new to SQLAlchemy so forgive me if this question is trivial..

Consider these 3 classes in *each their own file*:

**A.py:**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from main import Base

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "A"
    id  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Bs  = relationship("B", backref="A.id")
    Cs  = relationship("C", backref="A.id")
```

**B.py:**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from main import Base

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "B"
    id    = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    A_id  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("A.id"))
```

**C.py:**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from main import Base

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = "C"    
    id    = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    A_id  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("A.id"))
```

And then say we have a **main.py** something like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker

Base = declarative_base()

import A
import B
import C

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///test.db")
Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

a  = A.A()
b1 = B.B()
b2 = B.B()
c1 = C.C()
c2 = C.C()

a.Bs.append(b1)
a.Bs.append(b2)    
a.Cs.append(c1)
a.Cs.append(c2)    
session.add(a)
session.commit()
```

The above gives the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key assocated with column 'C.A_id' could not find table 'A' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

How do I share the declarative base across these files?

What is the "the right" way to accomplish this, considering that I might throw something like *Pylons* or *Turbogears* on top of this?

***edit 10-03-2011***

I found [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20110208013812/https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid_cookbook/dev/sqla.html#importing-all-sqlalchemy-models) description from the Pyramids framework which describes the problem and more importantly *verifies* that this is an actual issue and not (only) just my confused self that's the problem. Hope it can help others who dares down this dangerous road :)

Comment: @S.Lott The above works if all classes are in one file, so you tell me :)

Comment: Your code doesn't give this error, please post the code which has the actual error. Fix your imports, make it run so someone can actually _see_ your error.

Comment: @S.Lott My confusion was apparently centered around how to avoid cyclic imports. I come from C where this is not an issue. My apologies for taking up your time.

Comment: @joveha:  What?  What are these cyclic import problems you're having.  Please post the code with the cyclic imports so that we can explain how to decompose them and avoid the cycles.  There are too many vague hypotheticals in these comments.  What problem do you have?  Please be specific.

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The simplest solution to your problem will be to take `Base` out of the module that imports `A`, `B` and `C`;  Break the cyclic import.

### base.py

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
Base = declarative_base()
```

### a.py

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from base import Base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

class A(Base):
    __tablename__ = "A"
    id  = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    Bs  = relationship("B", backref="A.id")
    Cs  = relationship("C", backref="A.id")
```

### b.py

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from base import Base

class B(Base):
    __tablename__ = "B"
    id    = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    A_id  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("A.id"))
```

### c.py

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from base import Base

class C(Base):
    __tablename__ = "C"    
    id    = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    A_id  = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("A.id"))
```

### main.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship, backref, sessionmaker

import base


import a
import b
import c

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///:memory:")
base.Base.metadata.create_all(engine, checkfirst=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

a1 = a.A()
b1 = b.B()
b2 = b.B()
c1 = c.C()
c2 = c.C()

a1.Bs.append(b1)
a1.Bs.append(b2)    
a1.Cs.append(c1)
a1.Cs.append(c2)    
session.add(a1)
session.commit()
```

Works on my machine:

```
$ python main.py ; echo $?
0
```

Comment: Use `scoped_session`.

Comment: @user: session handling is unrelated to the question in this post, which is really a plain old python question (how do i import stuff?); but since i've got your attention, I would advise *strongly against* using `scoped_session`, unless you know why you need thread local storage;  The problem with using `scoped_session` is that it makes it all to easy to wind up with leaked transactions and stale data, with no explicit link to the point in your code when that might have happened.

Comment: This design pattern doesn't seem to work for python3. Is there any easy fix that is python3 compatible?

Comment: @computermacgyver: this pattern should work correctly across python versions.  Please ask a new question, so that you can include all of *your* code, and the errors you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks @dequestarmappartialsetattr . I found the error only happens when I tried to put a.py, b.py, c.py, and model.py into a separate module. I found the solution in that case was to include the base.py code in the module's \_\_init\_\_.py file instead. I've put the [code and more explanation here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644898/). Thanks for the reply.

Comment: Posting from the far future, where cars are made of lasers & this answer is still relevant/useful.  Thank you for the great code example -- it's exactly what I was looking to do, but was having trouble putting into SEO-friendly search terms.

Answer (score 24):

If I may add my bit of sense as well since I had the same problem. You need to import the classes in the file where you create the `Base = declarative_base()` AFTER you created the `Base` and the `Tables`. Short example how my project is set up:

**model/user.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from model import Base

class User(Base):
     __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    budgets = relationship('Budget')
```

**model/budget.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import *

from model import Base

class Budget(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'budget'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
```

**model/__init__.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

_DB_URI = 'sqlite:///:memory:'
engine = create_engine(_DB_URI)

Base = declarative_base()
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
DBSession = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = DBSession()

from .user import User
from .budget import Budget
```

Comment: Only in Python is something like this necessary, but I think it's a pretty elegant way to get around some thorns. Only difference is I needed to do `from . import Base` rather than `from model import Base`

Answer (score 8):

I'm using Python 2.7 + Flask 0.10 + SQLAlchemy 1.0.8 + Postgres 9.4.4.1

This boilerplate comes configured with a User and UserDetail models stored in the same file "models.py" in the "user" module. These classes both inherit from an SQLAlchemy base class.

All of the additional classes I've added to my project also derived from this base class, and as the models.py file grew larger, I decided to split the models.py file into one file per class, and ran into the problem described here.

The solution I found, along the same lines as @computermacgyver's Oct 23 2013 post, was to include all my classes to the **init**.py file of the new module I created to hold all the newly created class files. Looks like this:

```
/project/models/

__init__.py contains

from project.models.a import A 
from project.models.b import B
etc...
```

Comment: why do you think you need to use Flask?

Answer (score 0):

For me, adding `import app.tool.tool_entity` inside `app.py` and `from app.tool.tool_entity import Tool` inside `tool/__init__.py` was enough to get the table to be created. I haven't tried adding relationship yet, though.

Folder structure:

```
app/
  app.py
  tool/
    __init__.py
    tool_entity.py
    tool_routes.py
```

```py
# app/tool/tool_entity.py

from app.base import Base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String


class Tool(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'tool'

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
    fullname = Column(String)
    fullname2 = Column(String)
    nickname = Column(String)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User(name='%s', fullname='%s', nickname='%s')>" % (
            self.name, self.fullname, self.nickname)
```

```py
# app/tool/__init__.py
from app.tool.tool_entity import Tool
```

```py
# app/app.py

from flask import Flask
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from app.tool.tool_routes import tool_blueprint
from app.base import Base


db_dialect = 'postgresql'
db_user = 'postgres'
db_pwd = 'postgrespwd'
db_host = 'db'
db_name = 'db_name'
engine = create_engine(f'{db_dialect}://{db_user}:{db_pwd}@{db_host}/{db_name}', echo=True)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'hello world'


app.register_blueprint(tool_blueprint, url_prefix='/tool')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # you can add this import here, or anywhere else in the file, as debug (watch mode) is on, 
    # the table should be created as soon as you save this file.
    import app.tool.tool_entity
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, Python3, using SQLAlchemy in FASTAPI, I have a whole bunch of models, so using `models.py` as a sole home for all models is a nightmare. I also like to keep my schemas close to the models, so i created "model packages". The above answers were correct in that the importing sequence of the (db)classes was the issue. Because my directory structure is such where each "domain/entity" is a package. I just import package programatically

### Example Dir structure

```
| - domains 
| - __init__.py
| - database.py # <- Note here my DeclarativeBase is define here and 
     |          #  each modelpkg*/model.py imports it 
     |
     |- modelpkgA
        | - __init__.py
        | - model.py
        | - schema.py
     |
     | - modelPkgB
         | - __init__.py
         | - model.py
         | - [...]
```

I just added the following couple lines to `domains/__init__.py` to import 15+ "model" packages

```
import os 

import importlib

for pkg in os.listdir("concept"):
    if not pkg.endswith(".py") and not pkg.endswith("__"):
        importlib.import_module(f".{pkg}.model", "concept")
```