# sqlalchemy nested inheritance / polymorphic relationships

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a tree that looks like this, reflected via polymorphic inheritance:

```
      A
  /   |   \
  B   C   D
```

That works great, like:

```
class BaseModel(db.Model):     # Table A in diagram
    __tablename__ = "entities"

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True, nullable=False, server_default=func.nextval('guid_seq'))
    type_id = db.Column(db.SmallInteger, db.ForeignKey(EntityTypesModel.id))

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':'entity',
        'polymorphic_on':type_id,
        'with_polymorphic':'*'
    }

class BrandModel(BaseModel):   # Table B, C, D in diagram
    __tablename__ = 'brands'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, db.ForeignKey(StufffModel.id), primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    name = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)

    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity':ET_BRAND,
    }
```

The problem is I need to reflect something more like this:

```
              A
          /   |   \
          B   C   D
                /   \
                E    F
```

Where D is not only a polymorphic child of A but also the polymorphic parents of E & F.

It seems like I have to choose, D can either be a polymorphic child or it can be a parent - it can't be both.

Do I have any options here?

EDIT:

Just to tie this off, I ended up flattening the tree so it looks like:

```
      A
  /   |   \   \
 B    C    E   F
```

D is now gone  and the functionality it provided is in the children (E & F). I'll probably make the common parts a mixin or something.

Unfortunate but I couldn't spend more time on this particular issue.

Answer (score 5):

You definitely can do this. The code below is using the `declarative_base`, but shows the model setup which works. `D` class is both a parent and a child using class inheritance. However, the `polymorphic_identity` is stored only on the top level. Make sure you have all proper foreign keys and class inheritances set up.

*Note: you example defines type_id as Numeric, however the values seem to be Strings.*

```
Base = declarative_base(cls=_BaseMixin)
Base.query = session.query_property()

class BaseModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'entities'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    #type_id = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    type_id = Column(String, nullable=False)
    __mapper_args__ = {
        'polymorphic_identity': 'entity',
        'polymorphic_on':type_id,
        'with_polymorphic':'*'
    }

class ModelB(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'modelB'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'modelB'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entities.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

class ModelC(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'modelC'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'modelC'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entities.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

class ModelD(BaseModel):
    __tablename__ = 'modelD'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'modelD'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entities.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

class ModelE(ModelD):
    __tablename__ = 'modelE'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'modelE'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entities.id'), ForeignKey('modelD.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)

class ModelF(ModelD):
    __tablename__ = 'modelF'
    __mapper_args__ = {'polymorphic_identity': 'modelF'}
    id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('entities.id'), ForeignKey('modelD.id'), primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String, nullable=False)
```

Comment: So this looks like it is piggy backing off of the discriminator column type_id on ModelA. In reality Models D E F are discriminated by another column - maybe call it type_inner_id. However ModelD must remain polymorphic in relation to ModelA on the type_id column.

Comment: I believe this is the way that makes sense, and definitely would not call it piggy backing. Great you found a solution which is acceptable for you though.

Comment: How can you now tie a ForeignKey from a class like "class Ricky(Base)" towards table "entities" in BaseModel(Base) ? it keeps give me: sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError

Comment: What are the details of the error you get? And what is the model definition for it? As you can see from `ModelE` and `ModelF` above, you can define multiple foreign keys from the same column.

Comment: Would have to look at your code, but I can imagine there is some syntax issue, and not really a relationship related issue.

Comment: Not a syntax issue actually, a loop issue. see the above code works great when its in a single python script. but when I divide each model into its own file ( i.e: ModelE.py ) i need to start "import ModelD, BaseModel" and ModelD or BaseModel have ForeignKey that requires other files to be imported which happens to be ModelE, so it creates a loop of imports and throw an import error .... you familiar with this ?

Comment: You do not always need to import the models in order to define relationships, because you can just specify class name or table name in the relationship definitions. Also take a look at this question/answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7478403/sqlalchemy-classes-across-files.