# Getting empty sqlite DB and "(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table:..:" when trying to add item

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I wrote a general dbhandler module that can entangle data containers and uploade them to a mySQL database and is independent of the DB structure. Now I want to add a default or the possibility to shove the data into a sqlite DB. Structure-wise this is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19644898/change-in-import-handling-modules-from-python2-to-python3). The package looks like this:

```
dbhandler\
    dbhandler.py
    models\
       meta.py
       default\   
          default_DB_map.py 
          default_DB.cfg
```

default.cfg is the config file that describes the database for the dbhandler script. default_DB_map.py contains a map for each table of the DB, which inherits from BASE:

```
from sqlalchemy import BigInteger, Column, Integer, String, Float, DateTime
from sqlalchemy import Date, Enum
from ..meta import BASE

class db_info(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "info"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)
    project = Column(String)
    manufacturer = Column(String)
    ...

class db_probe(BASE):
    __tablename__ = "probe"

    probeid = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    id = Column(Integer)
    paraX = Column(String)
    ...
```

In meta.py I initialize the declarative_base object:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
BASE = declarative_base()
```

And eventually, I import BASE within the dbhandler.py and create the engine and session:

```
"DBHandler module"
...
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from models import meta #pylint: disable=E0401

....
class DBHandler(object):
     """Database handling

     Methods:
        - get_dict:         returns table row
        - add_item:         adds dict to DB table
        - get_table_keys:   gets list of all DB table keys
        - get_values:       returns all values of key in DB table
        - check_for_value:  checks if value is in DB table or not
        - upload:           uploads data container to DB
        - get_dbt:          returns DBTable object
    """
    def __init__(self, db_cfg=None):
        """Load credentials, DB structure and name of DB map from cfg file,
           create DB session. Create DBTable object to get table names of DB
           from cfg file, import table classes and get name of primary keys.

        Args:
            - db_cfg (yaml) : contains infos about DB structure and location 
                              of DB credentials.
        Misc:
            - cred = {"host"      : "...",
                      "database"  : "...",
                      "user"      : "...",
                      "passwd"    : "..."}
        """
        ...
        db_cfg = self.load_cfg(db_cfg)

        if db_cfg["engine"] == "sqlite":
            engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///mySQlite.db")
            meta.BASE.metadata.create_all(engine)
            session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            self.session = session()
        elif db_cfg["engine"] == "mysql+mysqlconnector":
            cred = self.load_cred(db_cfg["credentials"])
            engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(db_cfg["engine"]
                                              + "://"
                                              + cred["user"] + ":"
                                              + cred["passwd"] + "@"
                                              + cred["host"] + ":"
                                              + "3306" + "/"
                                              + cred["database"])
            session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
            self.session = session()
        else:
            self.log.warning("Unkown engine in DB cfg...")
        
        # here I'm importing the table classes stated in the config file
        self.dbt = DBTable(map_file=db_cfg["map"],
                           table_dict=db_cfg["tables"],
                           cr_dict=db_cfg["cross-reference"])
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong within the `if db_cfg["engine"] == "sqlite":` paragraph, but I can't figure out what.

The script is working just fine with the mySQL engine. When I initialize the handler object I'm getting an empty `mySQLite.db` file.
Adding something with that session yields:

```
(sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: info....
```

I can however use something like ´sqlalchemy.inspect´ on a table object without any errors. So I have the correct table objects at hand, but they are somehow not connected to the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For SQLite, apperently the import of the table classes needs to happen before the DB is created.

```
    # here I'm importing the table classes stated in the config file
    self.dbt = DBTable(map_file=db_cfg["map"],
                       table_dict=db_cfg["tables"],
                       cr_dict=db_cfg["cross-reference"])
```

(which is done via pydoc.locate btw) has to be done before

```
        engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///mySQlite.db")
        meta.BASE.metadata.create_all(engine)
        session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
        self.session = session()
```

is called. I thought this was not important since I imported BASE at the beginning and since it works just fine when using a different engine.

Comment: Your reasoning is off. The tables must've been constructed and exist in the `MetaData` regardless of the dialect in use. Your MySQL code just either happens to run the `Table` and Declarative class definitions before calling `create_all()`, or you've created the tables before.