# Importing SQLAlchemy models used in relationship?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I'm new to SQLAlchemy (using Python 3) and find the following puzzling. In my simple example, there are 2 model classes defined in separate files with a relationship linking them.

1. Is the setup correct? My code requires that `Animal.py` import `Owner` because a relationship is defined, otherwise `app/main.py` will throw an error about `Owner` class not found. However, the [official docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/basic_relationships.html#one-to-many) and other online examples do not appear to import the other classes that the current class has a relationship with.
2. Will having `model/__init__.py` be useful for my case? If so, what will it be used for? Saw [an example that used a `__init__.py` file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45613994/741099).

**Github Repo**: https://github.com/nyxynyx/sqlalchemy-class-import-error

**File Structure**

[image]

**app/main.py**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('..')

from lib.db import db_session
from models.foo.Animal import Animal

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Animal.query.all())
```

**models/foo/Animal.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from ..Base import Base
from .Owner import Owner    <-------------- !!!!! if not imported, error occurs when running main.py !!!!!

class Animal(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'animals'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
    owner_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('owners.id'))

    owner = relationship('Owner')
```

**models/Foo/Owner.py**

```
from sqlalchemy import *
from ..Base import Base

class Owner(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'owners'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(Text)
```

**lib/db.py**

```
import json
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

with open('../settings.json') as f:
    settings = json.load(f)
user, password, host, port, dbname = settings['db']['user'], settings['db']['password'], settings['db']['host'], settings['db']['port'], settings['db']['dbname']

connection_url =  f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{dbname}'
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
Session = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)
db_session = scoped_session(Session)
```

Comment: @AndrewAllen Any advantages of having 1 model class per file?

Answer (score 2):

The animal.py is fine.  The issue is that if owner.py is never imported, sqlalchemy never sees the Owner model/table so it never registers it into the Base metadata.  You can remove the import of Owner from animal.py into your main.py as

```
import models.foo.Owner
```

to see it work while keeping the separate model files.